# Preview photo in v-for Loop

Tags: javascript

I'm working with BootstrapVue and I've tried to have a photo preview in my v-for loop.

Everything works fine, except of `:src="'fileRequestSrc'+countTitle"` - In my developer tools I get following information:

[image]

This is how it looked before when I wrote it manually without the loop:

[image]

What is the mistake in my code respectively in this code line `:src="'fileRequestSrc'+countTitle"`  - thanks in advance!

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="countTitle in 3" :key="countTitle">
      <b-button v-b-toggle="'request'+countTitle" variant="danger btn-block mb-2">Upload {{countTitle}}</b-button>
      <b-collapse :id="'request'+countTitle" class="mt-2">
        <div class="m-2 mt-3">
          <table class="table table-striped mt-2">
            <tbody>
              <div class="mt-3 mb-2 ml-1">Upload</div>
              <b-form-file :v-model="'fileRequest'+countTitle" placeholder="Upload ..." class="mb-2"></b-form-file>
              <b-img v-if="'hasfileRequest'+countTitle" :src="'fileRequestSrc'+countTitle" class="mb-3" fluid block rounded></b-img>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </b-collapse>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>

const base64Encode = data =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(data);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
  });

export default {

  data() {
    return {

      fileRequest1: null,
      fileRequestSrc1: null, 
      fileRequest2: null,
      fileRequestSrc2: null, 
      fileRequest3: null,
      fileRequestSrc3: null, 
    } 
  },

  computed: {
    hasfileRequest1() {
      return !!this.fileRequest1;
    },
    hasfileRequest2() {
      return !!this.fileRequest2;
    },
    hasfileRequest3() {
      return !!this.fileRequest3;
    }
  },

  watch: {
    fileRequest1(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        if (newValue) {
          base64Encode(newValue)
            .then(value => {
              this.fileRequestSrc1 = value;
            })
            .catch(() => {
              this.fileRequestSrc1 = null;
            });
        } else {
          this.fileRequestSrc1 = null;
        }
      }
    },
    fileRequest2(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        if (newValue) {
          base64Encode(newValue)
            .then(value => {
              this.fileRequestSrc2 = value;
            })
            .catch(() => {
              this.fileRequestSrc2 = null;
            });
        } else {
          this.fileRequestSrc2 = null;
        }
      }
    },
    fileRequest3(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        if (newValue) {
          base64Encode(newValue)
            .then(value => {
              this.fileRequestSrc3 = value;
            })
            .catch(() => {
              this.fileRequestSrc3 = null;
            });
        } else {
          this.fileRequestSrc3 = null;
        }
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are encountering is a difference between what you are expecting vue to do and what vue is actually doing.

With this statement

```js
:src="'fileRequestSrc'+countTitle"
```

You are expecting vue to concatenate the string and then get the contents of the variable `fileRequestSrc1`, `fileRequestSrc1`, etc. However, what Vue is actually doing is concatenating the string together and assigning that to the value of src.

Currently, the way your logic is structured there are a few ways to accomplish what you want to do. Personally, the method I would take is to create an array of your variables and only access the one you want within your template.

However, none of these methods are really great. I would suggest restructuring your component to iterate over an array of objects, that contain the source for your image, as well as the file request. For example

```js
data(){
  return{
    files:[
       {id:0, src:null, request:null}
    ]
  }
}
```

then iterate over the files in the array instead of counting to 3.

Therefore your template would change to

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in files" :key="item.id">
      <b-button v-b-toggle="item.request" variant="danger btn-block mb-2">Upload {{item.id}}</b-button>
      <b-collapse :id="'request'+item" class="mt-2">
        <div class="m-2 mt-3">
          <table class="table table-striped mt-2">
            <tbody>
              <div class="mt-3 mb-2 ml-1">Upload</div>
              <b-form-file :v-model="item.request" placeholder="Upload ..." class="mb-2"></b-form-file>
              <b-img v-if="item.request" :src="item.src" class="mb-3" fluid block rounded></b-img>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </b-collapse>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then you would need to add a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) to encode the image as base 64. For example

```js
watch: {
    files: {
        deep: true, //used to watch the object's properties
        handler(newValue, oldValue){
            if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    base64Encode(newValue.src)
                        .then(value => {
                            newValue.src = value;
                        })
                        .catch(() => {
                            newValue.src = null;
                        });
                } else {
                    newValue.src = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At first, thanks for your time to help me out in my problem! - After trying it in my code I got the problem " invalid prop type check failed for prop except a String instead of a number". I've changed this (also in your answer above) - but my preview is not showing up.. is there something else I can do? Thanks!